# vector<double> being converted to vector<double, allocator<double>>

Tags: c++, vector, double, allocator

I'm creating a vector of doubles which I'm then trying to add to an object that I've defined. The problem is that my `vector<double>` is getting converted to a `vector<double, allocator<double>>` somehow. Can anyone see why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

double stringToDouble( const std::string& s )
{
  std::istringstream i(s);
  double x;
  if (!(i >> x))
    return 0;
  return x;
}

int main() {
    ifstream userDefine("userDefine.csv");
    string token, line;
    stringstream iss;
    int count = 0;
    vector<double> prices;

    while ( getline(userDefine, line) )
    {
        iss << line;
        while ( getline(iss, token, ',') )
        {
             double temp = stringToDouble(token);
             prices.push_back(temp);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then when adding to my object I get the following error:

> no matching function for call to `generatorTemplate::generatorTemplate(std::string&, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&......`

Comment: Fix the description in the body of the question, it seems to be incomplete wrt/ subject.

Comment: You should post some code that actually reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::vector<T>` is in fact a [`template < class T, class Alloc = allocator<T> > class vector;`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). As you can see it has allocator type parameter with a default value. What you are observing is expected. There is nothing wrong with that.